# htmlCode to PDF (Save) only javascript

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, jspdf, html2canvas

I am concerned for a few days... How save PDF for HTMLCode.

I find jsPDF!!

but I do not want to it because I was unable to use the CSS I want...T.T

so I think HTMLCode convert canvasImage(html2canvas and rasterizeHTML useing)

after canvasImage convert PDF!!

WOW starting is fantastic!! After a few moments later come trial it is CORS

HTML5 Canvas not suppot CORS image.

**I want to use canvas render CORS image**

help me please!!

example

```
html2canvas($("body")[0], {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
        var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        var pdf = new jsPDF();
  //window.open(img);
        pdf.addImage(img, 'png', 10, 10, 180, 160);
        pdf.save('test.pdf');
    }
});
```

Comment: where you are trying to add image in canvas? will you show the code.

Comment: function capture() {
 html2canvas($("body")[0], {
  onrendered: function(canvas) {
   var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
   var pdf = new jsPDF();
   pdf.addImage(img, 'png', 10, 10, 180, 160);
   pdf.save('test.pdf');
  }
 });
}